# "hdd" should be a synonym of "hard-disk"

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

There's [hard-disk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-disk) with close to 300 questions about hard disks. There's also [hdd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hdd) with another six questions on hard disks, and I'm not aware of any other common meaning of "hdd".

I propose to synonymize [hdd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hdd) to [hard-disk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-disk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And this is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). I just retagged all the questions which is applicable the tag. Along the way I removed the [hard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard) and [drive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drive) tags. Wait until 00:00 UTC for the changes being done.

Comment: I think we still lack the synonym for future questions, don't we?

Comment: @JensErat I added it